# getJSON is not a function when the second time I called it

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the first time I use jquery. The situation I'm facing here is that I need to parse some JSON file whose url is given by another JSON file.
Thus, I use the code

```js
var GlobalID = {};

function parseID() {
    var data;
    $.getJSON('https://taitk.org/api/algorithms', function(algorithms) {
        GlobalID = algorithms;
        console.log("ID got!");
        parseKeyword();
    });
}

function parseKeyword () {
    for(var i = 0; i < GlobalID.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON('https://taitk.org/api/algorithms/' + GlobalID[i].id, function(subdata) {
            console.log(subdata.data)
        });
    }
}
```

, where `parseID()` is a function to get the ID of each url, `parseKeyword()` is a function print out each url's data (written in the callback function, thus avoid the asynchronous function call).

However, the error I got is `keyword.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function` while the message "ID got!" is successfully printed. Also, the code work fine when I delete the `parseKeyword()`function, which is confusing for me because the first `getJson()` call seems to work while the second doesn't.

I'd like to figure out what kind of situation I'm facing to cause such error, thank you.

And, below is how I include those function in the html file:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
<script src="js/keyword.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    parseID()
</script>
```

Comment: After your assignment to GlobalID, add console.dir(GlobalID); to verify it is what you think it should be.  Also initialisation of GlobalID to {} is meaningless, since you reassign it, use if (GlobalID != undefined) to check if its initialised.

Comment: I have tried and it's working fine without any error in my machine.

Comment: @ParthRaval  Thx a lot. It turned out that I've mistakenly include another version of jquery in the `<body>` part of the file, OMG sry for wasting you guys' time......

Comment: @SPlatten Thx a lot for pointing out the redundant part of my code and giving me advices.

Answer (score 0):

The real cause is that I included the slim version of jquery in the `<body>` part along with the version mentioned in the question description. After removing it, it seems good.